How can i fix my wbesite code from my slug error in Wordpress
An entire page of "Warning: Attempt to read property "slug" on array in /home/clients/66796e484d83b14329d5ed1097846e31/sites/palomaconsulting.fr/wp-content/plugins/wpdm-elementor/src/widgets/PackagesWidget.php on line 55"
appeare when i go to my website, please tell me how can i fix it ?
Im not a pro, just a beginner
the error code is "
//include categories: multi select
$wpdmcategory_terms = get_terms(['taxonomoy' => 'wpdmcategory']);
foreach($wpdmcategory_terms as $k => $t){
$wpdmcategory_terms[$t->slug] = $t->name;
unset($wpdmcategory_terms[$k]);"
i'm just trying to acces to my website

Can you share the code involved, and your attempts to resolve the problem?

I only got this, i didnt attempts to resolve because i really don't know how,    //include categories: multi select
$wpdmcategory_terms = get_terms(['taxonomoy' => 'wpdmcategory']);
foreach($wpdmcategory_terms as $k => $t){
$wpdmcategory_terms[$t->slug] = $t->name;
unset($wpdmcategory_terms[$k]);

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it
